# Non-linearity of Wielemaker-Demoen Unification

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog, unification

This is a follow up to the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65884340/502187) about acyclic terms.
I am now interested in cyclic terms, and it seems their unification
is not anymore linear in the Wielemaker-Demoen unification.
The test case is basically:

```
?- X = f(f(X)), Y = f(f(f(Y))), X = Y.
X = Y, Y = f(f(f(Y))).
```

But we use larger number of function symbol iteration, and
we also use arity 2 of the function symbol, and not only arity 1.
For n=10,30,50,70 I get this quadratic behaviour, series 1 is
the measured time of (=)/2 and series 2 is n*(n+1)/2:

[image]

Is there some impossibility theorem that would say
unification for cyclic terms cannot be linear. Or otherwise
might unification for cyclic terms also fall under
the Patterson-Wegman unification, and therefore could
be made linear?

Open source:

**Linear or Exponential III?**
https://gist.github.com/jburse/279b6280ab4311de456e458a7386c1da#file-bart-pl

Comment: Cyclic terms are a bug. Enable the occurs check.